# How to find whether the string is a Lapindrome?

Tags: c, arrays, string, codeblocks

The following code is giving correct output as given on the codechef problem page: http://www.codechef.com/problems/LAPIN
but getting wrong answer on submission
please tell me the possible problem with my code

here is the question

Lapindrome is defined as a string which when split in the middle, gives two halves having the same characters and same frequency of each character. If there are odd number of characters in the string, we ignore the middle character and check for lapindrome. For example gaga is a lapindrome, since the two halves ga and ga have the same characters with same frequency. Also, abccab, rotor and xyzxy are a few examples of lapindromes. Note that abbaab is NOT a lapindrome. The two halves contain the same characters but their frequencies do not match. 
Your task is simple. Given a string, you need to tell if it is a lapindrome.

Input:

First line of input contains a single integer T, the number of test cases.

Each test is a single line containing a string S composed of only lowercase English alphabet.

Output:

For each test case, output on a separate line: "YES" if the string is a lapindrome and "NO" if it is not.

and here is the code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    int f,t,mid,len;
    char arr[1000];
    int left[125],right[125];
    scanf("%d",&t);
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        f=0;
        scanf("%s",arr);
        memset(left,0,sizeof(left));
        memset(right,0,sizeof(right));
        len=strlen(arr);
        for(int i=0;i<len/2;i++)
            left[arr[i]]++;
        for(int i=(len+1)/2;i<len;i++)
            right[arr[i]]++;
        for(int i=0;i<strlen(arr);i++)
        {
            if(left[arr[i]]!=right[arr[i]])
                f++;
            break;
        }
        if(f==0)
            printf("YES\n");
        else
            printf("NO\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For starters, *it's not indented*.

Comment: if you are talking about the format of the code
then please dont mind that i was having problem with the site format
just tell me the possible error in the code

Comment: Have you tried feeding it some sample input, other than the invisible input from the codechef submission engine? I mean, make up some input for which you know what the response should be, and feed it into your code to see what comes out.

Comment: You also seem to be writing C, not C++

Comment: @InsaynAsasin, Paste the code, highlight it, press the formatting button. We can't just ignore the formatting because it makes the code impossible to read. If we can't read the code, the question loses a lot of its value.

Comment: @InsaynAsasin "please dont mind that [...] just tell me the possible error" - we can't just "not mind that" -- your code is **unreadable,** and we cannot possibly be bothered to try decipher it in its current form. It is **for a very practical reason** that we demand code be formatted when you post it.

Comment: please tell me the error now...

Comment: i have done as @chris said

Comment: and @shoover i have tried many strings of my own and i am getting the answer as i think it shud be...

Comment: Hint: Look at the requirements for the first line of input.

Comment: @Angew please have a look at the problem again.
I hope it looks good now

Comment: @shoover
first line is the number of testcases and its <=100
i thing that is not the problem or else it shouldn't have worked for the other cases

Comment: What happens if you feed it something that is not a number in the first line? For these problems you need to consider all of the possible types of input that may be given to you, not just the "happy path" of what is expected.

Comment: @shoover
the input format is strictly followed
testcases are to be integer values <=100 and then the strings follow
i have seen to it

Comment: @shoover Not really. In these online judges, input format is specified exactly and followed strictly. There is no need for error checking.

Comment: @Angew, ah, my bad. I've not done codechef, only spoj, which IIRC sometimes gives you edge cases in their input.

Comment: @shoover I think the same applies to SPOJ. When they say a line contains an integer, it contains an integer.

Comment: @InsaynAsasin: If I were going to answer your question, I would have posted an answer rather than a comment. The original lack of indentation made answering the question more difficult. (Thank you for fixing it, but I think others have probably addressed what you were asking about.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you read up on modularity; it'll make your life easier.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BOOL unsigned char
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

unsigned string_length(char *string)
{
    unsigned counter = 0;

    while (string[counter++] != '\0') { }

    return counter - 1;
}

BOOL are_equal(unsigned *a, unsigned *b, int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        if (a[i] != b[i])
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    return TRUE;
}

BOOL is_lapindrome(char *string)
{
    unsigned left[26] = { 0 }, right[26] = { 0 },
             str_len = string_length(string);

    if (str_len < 2)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= str_len / 2 - 1; ++i)
    {
        left[string[i] - 'a']++;
    }

    for (i = (str_len + 1) / 2; i < str_len; ++i)
    {
        right[string[i] - 'a']++;
    }

    return are_equal(left, right, 26);
}

int main()
{
    char *list[6] =
    {
        "gaga",
        "abcde",
        "rotor",
        "xyzxy",
        "abbaab",
        "ababc"
    };

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        printf("%s\n", is_lapindrome(list[i]) == TRUE ? "YES" : "NO");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: that is impressive!
i will surely try to make my programs simpler and as you said, separated into different modules...

Answer (score 1):

1. Your buffer is one byte too short - a string of 1000 characters requires 1001 `char`s, the last one taken by the `nul` terminator.
2. "lowercase English alphabet" sounds a bit ambiguous - I'd say that by some interpretation, it could contain spaces. If so, the input will be read incorrectly.

I can't see other problems right now, but I'd strongly suspect the first one.

Comment: it says the string s is greater than or equal to 2 and less that or equal to 1000 so i guess initializing it to 1000 is  not worng

Comment: @InsaynAsasin Did you even read what I wrote? A string of 1000 characters requires **1001** bytes to store. You do know C-style strings are stored with an extra terminating 0 byte, don't you?

Comment: ok... now i get your point!